# MAUI Keyword Extraction : Command not found

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run MAUI for keyword extraction. However, when I run this command:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar maui-standalone-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar train -l data/docs/fao_train/ -m data/models/keyword_extraction_model -v none -o 2
```

It shows `$: command not found`

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is that the _exact_ command you ran?

Comment: yea. After placing the maui jar file in Rake folder, I ran this exact command.

Comment: The error message you show is what you would get if you typed `$` in the terminal and hit enter. Are you sure you didn't have a `$` at the beginning of the command? Perhaps you copied it from a tutorial and included the `$`?

Comment: thanks! I guess, that was the mistake, because it worked this time.

Comment: Ah, good. OK, I posted an answer so the question can be [marked as solved](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you copied the command from a tutorial somewhere and included the `$` from the prompt. Often, tutorials use `$` to differentiate between the command you run and its output. The `$` symbolizes the shell prompt that you get when you open a terminal. It should not be included in the command itself.  That's the error you would get if you ran:

```
$ java -Xmx1024m -jar maui-standalone-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar train -l data/docs/fao_train/ -m data/models/keyword_extraction_model -v none -o 2
```

For example:

[image]

So, just run it again, but without the `$`:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar maui-standalone-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar train -l data/docs/fao_train/ -m data/models/keyword_extraction_model -v none -o 2
```